# C#: Using a timer on a winform to alter a chart, timer needs a separate method, chart data can't be edited from the separate method

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3VwS.png)I'm making a little project to help me get more antiquated with both charts and winforms. I decided to make an xy graph that simulates projectile motion (with x being x displacement and y being y displacement, and the parametric variable t for time). I was able to get it working fine, but a friend challenged me to try and make it animate the graph real time. I found some basic stuff about timers and elapsed time and all, but then I found out that I got myself into a trouble. The doing something on each timer elapse required timer elapse to call on an event (which is apparently a thread? I'm not really familiar with threads at all), and the series that I used for my winforms chart line cannot be edited from a thread (which I assume for all intents and purposes in this case is just a method?) except the one it was created on, according to Visual Studio's error.

I'm a pretty darn new programmer, I know c# to an extant, but so far I am much more comfortable using it without binding it to objects (I've been told I use c# like C?). So even though this may be super over complicated, it's just what I came up with after doing a bit of research and exploring myself. I have not tried much else here, and I've got no idea what to do to solve it. I'm pretty stuck

```
public InputAndChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
    private System.Timers.Timer totalTimer;
    public int i;

    private void Model_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region x suvat variables
        double initialsx = Convert.ToDouble(Initialsx.Text);
        double sx;
        double ux = Convert.ToDouble(Initialux.Text);
        double vx = 5;
        double ax = Convert.ToDouble(Initialax.Text);
        #endregion
        #region y suvat variables
        double initialsy = Convert.ToDouble(Initialsy.Text);
        double sy;
        double uy = Convert.ToDouble(Initialuy.Text);
        double vy = -93;
        double ay = Convert.ToDouble(Initialay.Text);
        #endregion
        #region Setting other Variables
        double t = 10;
        double totalTime = Convert.ToDouble(TotalTime.Text);
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        totalTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        totalTimer.Interval = totalTime * 1000;
        totalTimer.AutoReset = false;
        #endregion

        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        aTimer.Elapsed += ThreadProcSafe;
        totalTimer.Elapsed += DisableaTimer;

        #region Previous for loop
        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < totalTime * 10; i++)
        {
            t = 0.1 * i;
            sx = initialsx + ux * t + 0.5 * ax * Math.Pow(t, 2);
            sy = initialsy + uy * t + 0.5 * ay * Math.Pow(t, 2);
            chart1.Series["Curve 1"].Points.AddXY(sx, sy);
        }
        */
        #endregion

        #region Random copied test points
        /*
        Random rdn = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY
                            (rdn.Next(0, 10), rdn.Next(0, 10));
            chart1.Series["test2"].Points.AddXY
                            (rdn.Next(0, 10), rdn.Next(0, 10));
        }
        */
        #endregion

        chart1.Series["Curve 1"].ChartType =
                            SeriesChartType.FastLine;
        chart1.Series["Curve 1"].Color = Color.Red;

    }

    private void DisableaTimer(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void ThreadProcSafe(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        #region x suvat variables
        double initialsx = Convert.ToDouble(Initialsx.Text);
        double sx;
        double ux = Convert.ToDouble(Initialux.Text);
        double vx = 5;
        double ax = Convert.ToDouble(Initialax.Text);
        #endregion
        #region y suvat variables
        double initialsy = Convert.ToDouble(Initialsy.Text);
        double sy;
        double uy = Convert.ToDouble(Initialuy.Text);
        double vy = -93;
        double ay = Convert.ToDouble(Initialay.Text);
        #endregion
        double t;
        t = 0.1 * i;
        sx = initialsx + ux * t + 0.5 * ax * Math.Pow(t, 2);
        sy = initialsy + uy * t + 0.5 * ay * Math.Pow(t, 2);
        chart1.Series["Curve 1"].Points.AddXY(sx, sy);
        i += 1;
    }
```

Well, the ideal output I was hoping for is that the chart drawn in this case would be that it would plot a point every second. Once I've got that working, I'd tweak the time so that it feels like a more smooth curve. Hell, I'll most likely make the timer proportional to the total time or so.

I've added this image to help give an idea of what I want from this. Quick clarification:
User inputs the initial position as xtextbox ytextbox
User inputs the initial velocity as a vector (aka in terms of i and j, but without the i and j)
User inputs the constant acceleration as a vector, same as velocity.
And the user inputs the amount of time that they would like to model this for.
User then clicks model to draw the graph.
User can click clear to empty the graph.

P.S. I have the clear button, but I would like to ideally be able to model multiple projectiles on the same graph. I know the easier way is probably to add a series, or as many as I wanna be allowed to model, but I wanted to ask if there is a way to make the next point in the same series a new position without actually having a line from the end of the chart up to the new position?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired result without explicit use of the Timer.

Make asynchronous method which after every given interval will update a chart.
And we need two more helper variables

```
private int _intervalMilliseconds;
private bool _runUpdating;

private void UpdateChart()
{
    // x suvat variables
    double initialsx = Convert.ToDouble(Initialsx.Text);
    double ux = Convert.ToDouble(Initialux.Text);
    double vx = 5;
    double ax = Convert.ToDouble(Initialax.Text);

    // y suvat variables
    double initialsy = Convert.ToDouble(Initialsy.Text);
    double uy = Convert.ToDouble(Initialuy.Text);
    double vy = -93;
    double ay = Convert.ToDouble(Initialay.Text);

    double t = 0.1 * i;
    double sx = initialsx + ux * t + 0.5 * ax * Math.Pow(t, 2);
    double sy = initialsy + uy * t + 0.5 * ay * Math.Pow(t, 2);

    chart1.Series["Curve 1"].Points.AddXY(sx, sy);
    i += 1;
}

private async Task StartUpdatingChart()
{
    while (_runUpdating)
    {
        UpdateChart();
        await Task.Delay(_intervalMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Then start updating chart within FormLoad eventhandler for example

```
// We need preserve updating task to close it properly
private Task _updatingTask;

private async void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _runUpdating = true;
     _intervalMilliseconds = 1000;
     _updatingTask = StartUpdatingChart();
}

private async void FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _runUpdating = false;
     // await for task to be completed
     await _updatingTask;
}
```

With asynchronous approach all operations will be executed on the same thread. Except `Task.Delay` which will use Timer in the background.

Comment: Hey there. Thank you very much for the reply. I think I sort of understand what you were getting at there. To try and understand it better, I thought I'd start by copying it and pasting it into my code, and seeing what it does. Thing is, StartUpdatingChart() is not a method that I have, was I meant to make one or so? Additionally, correct me if I'm wrong but the FormLoad method starts on, well, the form loading. I don't want it to try and graph it from the moment the form loads, since I have a couple of variables needed and a button to trigger the graphing.

Comment: @NurLuskiLevi, if you copied the code then `StartUpdatingChart` should be in that copy (it is in the answer) ;). You can start updating graph from any other method, `FormLoad` was an example.